# "Element not found 0x80070490" when installing ASP .Net Core tooling

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual studio 2015 Update 3, I'm trying to install asp .net core Tooling package(DotNetCore.1.0.1-VS2015Tools.Preview2.0.3.exe)

I get this by either downloading it separately or when clicking at the 
"ASP .NET 5 RC" template when creating a new ASP Net Web Application in VS.
After a while during the installation I get the error

> "Element not found 0x80070490"

(also see log file at bottom)

After some searching:

I have tried starting it from cmd (as admin) with flag SKIP_VSU_CHECK=1
and I have tried to reinstall VC++ Distributables, these just gives me more errors when creating projects from templates. I have english as my VS language. I have also tried downloaded the v1.1, it installs ok but I can't see any difference in Visual studio

This is the end of the log file after my installation has failed:

> [1E4C:1E48][2017-01-17T09:58:01]i360: Creating a system restore point.
>
> [1E4C:1E48][2017-01-17T09:58:01]i361: Created a system restore point.
>
> [1E4C:1E48][2017-01-17T09:58:01]i371: Updating session, registration
>   key:
>   SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{da280276-4f5b-4918-8d40-20ca56dfa535},
>   resume: Active, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
>
> [1E4C:1FD0][2017-01-17T09:58:02]i305: Verified acquired payload:
>   SetupBlocked_Install at path: C:\ProgramData\Package
>   Cache.unverified\SetupBlocked_Install, moving to:
>   C:\ProgramData\Package
>   Cache\f727b670-667c-3e6f-aafb-e48a72a2dea2\SetupBlocked_69.exe.
>
> [1E4C:1E48][2017-01-17T09:58:02]i301: Applying execute package:
>   SetupBlocked_Install, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package
>   Cache\f727b670-667c-3e6f-aafb-e48a72a2dea2\SetupBlocked_69.exe,
>   arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package
>   Cache\f727b670-667c-3e6f-aafb-e48a72a2dea2\SetupBlocked_69.exe"'
>
> [1E4C:1FD0][2017-01-17T09:58:02]i305: Verified acquired payload:
>   Preparation_Uninstall_ASPNET at path: C:\ProgramData\Package
>   Cache.unverified\Preparation_Uninstall_ASPNET, moving to:
>   C:\ProgramData\Package
>   Cache\50e2672c-aefb-300c-8301-d8ebba628476\Preparation_69.exe.
>
> [1E4C:1FD0][2017-01-17T09:58:02]i304: Verified existing payload:
>   ANCM_IISExpress_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package
>   Cache{C2BB4C41-59DC-487E-9CCF-1E21C3AC9139}v1.0.1967\packages\ancm_iis_express_x64_en_69.msi.
>
> [0D30:1FB0][2017-01-17T09:58:02]w343: Prompt for source of package:
>   DotNetCLI_x64, payload: DotNetCLI_x64, path:
>   C:\Users\MYACCOUNTNAME\Downloads\packages\DotNetCore.1.0.1-SDK.1.0.0.Preview2-003131-x64.exe
>
> [0D30:1FB0][2017-01-17T09:58:02]i338: Acquiring package:
>   DotNetCLI_x64, payload: DotNetCLI_x64, download from:
>   https://download.microsoft.com/download/F/6/E/F6ECBBCC-B02F-424E-8E03-D47E9FA631B7/packages/DotNetCore.1.0.1-SDK.1.0.0.Preview2-003131-x64.exe
>
> [1E4C:1FD0][2017-01-17T09:58:09]i305: Verified acquired payload:
>   DotNetCLI_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package
>   Cache.unverified\DotNetCLI_x64, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package
>   Cache\8B4ACC662D4A8759AB418CA5F92FE4721D21B190\packages\DotNetCore.1.0.1-SDK.1.0.0.Preview2-003131-x64.exe.
>
> [0D30:1FB0][2017-01-17T09:58:09]w343: Prompt for source of package:
>   DotNetVersionManager_x64, payload: DotNetVersionManager_x64, path:
>   C:\Users\MYACCOUNTNAME\Downloads\packages\DotNetVersionManager-x64_rc1.msi
>
> [0D30:1FB0][2017-01-17T09:58:09]i338: Acquiring package:
>   DotNetVersionManager_x64, payload: DotNetVersionManager_x64, download
>   from:
>   https://download.microsoft.com/download/F/6/E/F6ECBBCC-B02F-424E-8E03-D47E9FA631B7/packages/DotNetVersionManager-x64_rc1.msi
>
> [1E4C:1FD0][2017-01-17T09:58:10]i305: Verified acquired payload:
>   DotNetVersionManager_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package
>   Cache.unverified\DotNetVersionManager_x64, moving to:
>   C:\ProgramData\Package
>   Cache{4EC36977-42B9-3C18-A692-B9DEE7404484}v1.0.11123.0\packages\DotNetVersionManager-x64_rc1.msi.
>
> [0D30:1FB0][2017-01-17T09:58:10]w343: Prompt for source of package:
>   AspNetCoreLocalFeed, payload: AspNetCoreLocalFeed, path:
>   C:\Users\MYACCOUNTNAME\Downloads\packages\AspNetCoreLocalFeed_69.msi
>
> [0D30:1FB0][2017-01-17T09:58:10]i338: Acquiring package:
>   AspNetCoreLocalFeed, payload: AspNetCoreLocalFeed, download from:
>   https://download.microsoft.com/download/F/6/E/F6ECBBCC-B02F-424E-8E03-D47E9FA631B7/packages/AspNetCoreLocalFeed_69.msi
>
> [0D30:1E1C][2017-01-17T09:58:15]i319: Applied execute package:
>   SetupBlocked_Install, result: 0x0, restart: None
>
> [1E4C:1E48][2017-01-17T09:58:15]i301: Applying execute package:
>   Preparation_Uninstall_ASPNET, action: Install, path:
>   C:\ProgramData\Package
>   Cache\50e2672c-aefb-300c-8301-d8ebba628476\Preparation_69.exe,
>   arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package
>   Cache\50e2672c-aefb-300c-8301-d8ebba628476\Preparation_69.exe" /d'
>
> [0D30:1E1C][2017-01-17T09:58:15]i319: Applied execute package:
>   Preparation_Uninstall_ASPNET, result: 0x0, restart: None
>
> [1E4C:1E48][2017-01-17T09:58:15]i301: Applying execute package:
>   ANCM_IISExpress_x64, action: Repair, path: C:\ProgramData\Package
>   Cache{C2BB4C41-59DC-487E-9CCF-1E21C3AC9139}v1.0.1967\packages\ancm_iis_express_x64_en_69.msi,
>   arguments: ' ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT="1" MSIFASTINSTALL="7"'
>
> [1E4C:1E48][2017-01-17T09:58:18]e000: Error 0x80070652: Failed to run
>   maintanance mode for MSI package.
>
> [1E4C:1E48][2017-01-17T09:58:18]e000: Error 0x80070652: Failed to
>   execute MSI package.
>
> [0D30:1E1C][2017-01-17T09:58:18]e000: Error 0x80070652: Failed to
>   configure per-machine MSI package.
>
> [0D30:1E1C][2017-01-17T09:58:18]w348: Application requested retry of
>   package: ANCM_IISExpress_x64, encountered error: 0x80070652.
>   Retrying...
>
> [1E4C:1E48][2017-01-17T09:58:21]i301: Applying execute package:
>   ANCM_IISExpress_x64, action: Repair, path: C:\ProgramData\Package
>   Cache{C2BB4C41-59DC-487E-9CCF-1E21C3AC9139}v1.0.1967\packages\ancm_iis_express_x64_en_69.msi,
>   arguments: ' ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT="1" MSIFASTINSTALL="7"'
>
> [1E4C:1FD0][2017-01-17T09:58:24]i305: Verified acquired payload:
>   AspNetCoreLocalFeed at path: C:\ProgramData\Package
>   Cache.unverified\AspNetCoreLocalFeed, moving to:
>   C:\ProgramData\Package
>   Cache{37BEAEAD-FEB0-3B82-9B32-710E0776FFAD}v1.0.20907.0\packages\AspNetCoreLocalFeed_69.msi.
>
> [1E4C:1FD0][2017-01-17T09:58:24]i304: Verified existing payload:
>   NuGetVS14 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package
>   Cache{08D9540E-77B1-37B3-909A-813DAA5523D0}v3.5.0.1484\packages\NuGetVisualStudio14_69.msi.
>
> [1E4C:1FD0][2017-01-17T09:58:24]i304: Verified existing payload:
>   cabFB5D09005B6CCD7291B309F84DC6E0E2 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package
>   Cache{08D9540E-77B1-37B3-909A-813DAA5523D0}v3.5.0.1484\packages\nuget14_VisualStudio.cab.
>
> [0D30:1FB0][2017-01-17T09:58:24]w343: Prompt for source of package:
>   WebToolsExtensionsVS14, payload: WebToolsExtensionsVS14, path:
>   C:\Users\MYACCOUNTNAME\Downloads\packages\WebToolsExtensionsVS14_69.msi
>
> [0D30:1FB0][2017-01-17T09:58:24]i338: Acquiring package:
>   WebToolsExtensionsVS14, payload: WebToolsExtensionsVS14, download
>   from:
>    https://download.microsoft.com/download/F/6/E/F6ECBBCC-B02F-424E-8E03-D47E9FA631B7/packages/WebToolsExtensionsVS14_69.msi
>
> [0D30:1E1C][2017-01-17T09:58:27]i319: Applied execute package:
>   ANCM_IISExpress_x64, result: 0x0, restart: None
>
> [1E4C:1E48][2017-01-17T09:58:27]i325: Registering dependency:
>   {da280276-4f5b-4918-8d40-20ca56dfa535} on package provider:
>   IISExpress_AspNetCore_Module,x64, package: ANCM_IISExpress_x64
>
> [1E4C:1E48][2017-01-17T09:58:27]i301: Applying execute package:
>   DotNetCLI_x64, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package
>   Cache\8B4ACC662D4A8759AB418CA5F92FE4721D21B190\packages\DotNetCore.1.0.1-SDK.1.0.0.Preview2-003131-x64.exe,
>   arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package
>   Cache\8B4ACC662D4A8759AB418CA5F92FE4721D21B190\packages\DotNetCore.1.0.1-SDK.1.0.0.Preview2-003131-x64.exe"
>   /quiet /norestart'
>
> [1E4C:1FD0][2017-01-17T09:58:39]i305: Verified acquired payload:
>   WebToolsExtensionsVS14 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package
>   Cache.unverified\WebToolsExtensionsVS14, moving to:
>   C:\ProgramData\Package
>   Cache{BFC344B0-DCDE-36EB-AB05-CB194F2BE946}v14.1.21111.0\packages\WebToolsExtensionsVS14_69.msi.
>
> [0D30:1FB0][2017-01-17T09:58:39]w343: Prompt for source of package:
>   DotNetToolsVS14, payload: DotNetToolsVS14, path:
>   C:\Users\MYACCOUNTNAME\Downloads\packages\DotNetToolsVS14_69.msi
>
> [0D30:1FB0][2017-01-17T09:58:39]i338: Acquiring package:
>   DotNetToolsVS14, payload: DotNetToolsVS14, download from:
>   https://download.microsoft.com/download/F/6/E/F6ECBBCC-B02F-424E-8E03-D47E9FA631B7/packages/DotNetToolsVS14_69.msi
>
> [1E4C:1FD0][2017-01-17T09:58:40]i305: Verified acquired payload:
>   DotNetToolsVS14 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package
>   Cache.unverified\DotNetToolsVS14, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package
>   Cache{0DFDFA4C-B434-3535-95DA-C5DAFDD5B1CF}v14.1.21111.0\packages\DotNetToolsVS14_69.msi.
>
> [1E4C:1FD0][2017-01-17T09:58:40]i305: Verified acquired payload:
>   Preparation_ASPNET at path: C:\ProgramData\Package
>   Cache.unverified\Preparation_ASPNET, moving to:
>   C:\ProgramData\Package
>   Cache\4f0b7b02-eb23-3261-a713-a05662eaa53e\Preparation_69.exe.
>
> [1E4C:1E48][2017-01-17T09:58:45]e000: Error 0x80070490: Process
>   returned error: 0x490
>
> [1E4C:1E48][2017-01-17T09:58:45]e000: Error 0x80070490: Failed to
>   execute EXE package.
>
> [0D30:1E1C][2017-01-17T09:58:45]e000: Error 0x80070490: Failed to
>   configure per-machine EXE package.
>
> [0D30:1E1C][2017-01-17T09:58:45]i319: Applied execute package:
>   DotNetCLI_x64, result: 0x80070490, restart: None
>
> [0D30:1E1C][2017-01-17T09:58:45]e000: Error 0x80070490: Failed to
>   execute EXE package.
>
> [1E4C:1E48][2017-01-17T09:58:45]i351: Removing cached package:
>   DotNetCLI_x64, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package
>   Cache\8B4ACC662D4A8759AB418CA5F92FE4721D21B190\
>
> [1E4C:1E48][2017-01-17T09:58:45]i372: Session end, registration key:
>   SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{da280276-4f5b-4918-8d40-20ca56dfa535},
>   resume: ARP, restart: None, disable resume: No
>
> [1E4C:1E48][2017-01-17T09:58:45]i371: Updating session, registration
>   key:
>   SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{da280276-4f5b-4918-8d40-20ca56dfa535},
>   resume: ARP, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
>
> [0D30:1E1C][2017-01-17T09:58:46]i399: Apply complete, result:
>   0x80070490, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No

Answer (score 2):

I had a exact same problem but i have found a solution, hope it will help you or somebody else.

First i download all packages needed to install DotNetCore.1.0.1-VS2015Tools.Preview2.0.3 using commad (in cmd):

```
DotNetCore.1.0.1-VS2015Tools.Preview2.0.3.exe /layout
```

It creates packages directory with a bunch of .msi files.
First error in log is about DotNetToolsVS14_69.msi, so I have install it.
Then I tried to install DotNetCore.1.0.1-SDK.1.0.0.Preview2-003131-x64.exe,
but error appeard "Element not found 0x80070490" regarding Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable 14.0.24215. I couldn't install it beceause i already have version 14.10 (from VS 2017). So I uninstall version 14.10 install 14.0.24215 and then i was able to install DotNetCore.1.0.1-SDK.1.0.0.Preview2-003131-x64.exe.

Next step was to try again with DotNetCore.1.0.1-VS2015Tools.Preview2.0.3.exe and it install successfully.